# upgrade from mongodb 2.6 to mongodb 3.0.12 getting authentication error in rails + heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

upgraded mlab from 2.6 to 3.0.12. am getting following error in console while trying to connect to mongodb

```
Moped::Errors::AuthenticationFailure: The operation:
#<Moped::Protocol::Commands::Authenticate
```

please find my Gemfile.lock below

```
rails (3.1.1)
ruby 1.9.3p551

  moped (~> 1.2)
moped (1.5.3)

  mongo (1.11.1)
  mongoid (3.0.23)
mongo
mongoid
```

Comment: Are you able to remove your Gemfile.lock and redo bundle install ?